# i get an error while i check for nil in closure

Tags: ios, swift, closures

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

         var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/London/forecasts/latest")

        if url != nil {
            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                var urlContenent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            })

        }
        else{

        }


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

this is the error that i get

> Cannot invoke '!=' with an argument list of type '(@lvalue NSURL,
>   NilLiteralConvertible)'

Comment: I think you need to define `var url`, as `var url:NSURL=nil;` then `url=<your code>`

Comment: Do you use Swift 2 or Xcode 7? I can't reproduce the error that you report in Swift 1.2.

Comment: BTW, don't forget `task.resume()`.

Comment: Are you sure that NSURL returns an optional value? You might be trying to unwrap the unwrap able?

Answer (score 0):

Not technically an answer to your question but you could use an `if let` statement

```
if let url = url{
  let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
  var urlContenent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
```

This will also check if your url is nil, if it is not it will continue the if statement. If you use this you also no longer need to force unwrap the `url`

Answer (score 0):

You are using Xcode 6.0.1, which predates failable initializers, which were [introduced in Xcode 6.1](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17). Thus, your URL is not an optional, generating the error you describe (comparing a non-optional value to `nil`).

There have been significant changes in Swift since 6.0.1. I might advise upgrading to the current production version of Xcode.

Comment: am now upgrading Xcode i use Xcode 6.0.1 because it's the one used in the tutorial that i study with...